# restricting data access

Tags: encryption, data-protection

I have a group of 30 developers who have access to a high sensitive database for debugging purposes. All data in the database are not encrypted. If we have a concern to protect some columns e.g. Salary in a table, what is the best way to do so?

1) What is the best way to ensure the developer is incapable of viewing other's salary? But authorize & appoint a developer only when it is needed.

I am thinking of data encryption to encrypt the salary column. But how do i grant the access to the developer in the fastest way if we encounter an issue on the salary? Granting the decryption code to the developer will again allow him to check on other salary.

Any advise?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate dev environment for development anyway, so you could simply NULL the salary column there (or give it random values).

For final production data test (which also needs to be done), you wouldn't need all 30 developers to have access so assign a few to do it and give them access to the prod data.

You can also consider row based security by assigning users to roles, and only TRUSTED_DEV gets to see all the records, but that is generally a pain (management of roles, testing takes longer as they arent sure if it is a bug or they dont have the right access)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason those 30 developers need the production access because they need to support other tables beside the Payroll table.  Are we allow to grant the production database access to all 30 but limit the Payroll table to only a few person?

Comment: @belinq use the role solution suggested in the third paragraph of the answer if only a few users need access to the table

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am thinking is there a way for the SQL server to read who has performed the READ/Select statement in any of the important table? I believe this will be the best and easiest way to track who has misuse the access to read other employee data. From there we can generate a report by month..

Comment: @acutesoftware Hi do you have a chance to check my last reply ? Thanks :)

Comment: In terms of tracking who has accessed a table, yes there is a way - this more of a question to DB admins, but there are audit tables which you can use which track who accesses what table. Make a view of this audit table and filter on the secret table and you will be able to see who accessed it. Though really, that is shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted - it really is better to restrict access to the table in the first place rather than chase down people who accessed it. Cheers

Comment: @acutesoftware Great thanks. We had restricted the table access to only a few persons. Ok here is my overall understanding. Since SQL server can track who has perform READ transaction to a "sensitive table", i would say it is possible for us to generate a report too? Can we create a monthly report to show who has run the select query with their userID? If we can, this will surely work as a best way to track and fine those who has misuse the access. Do you have any link for that tutorial if possible? Great Thanks again :)